# Can the Samsung Galaxy Note II stock camera app be transplanted to a custom firmware?

Tags: applications, custom-roms, camera, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I've had a Sprint Samsung Galaxy Note II (SPH-L900) for 2½ years. I've always liked the stock Camera app that it came with, and I've missed having it around since I replaced the stock firmware with CyanogenMod. As it happens, due to technical difficulties it was necessary for me to reinstall the stock firmware recently, and there was my little friend again, "Camera" (v1.5). Is there any way to capture that camera app from the stock firmware and transplant it to CM 12.1 (or any other custom firmware)?

Comment: FYI: There are some older XDA threads that indicate people were working on this at some time:  
  
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1883192  
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2034867  
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2054640

Comment: FYI part 2: your links refer to porting the Note 2 camera to other samsung devices - and even those devices are required to run a touchwiz-based STOCK rom - there is no way installing it on a aosp and no one is/was willing to put that much effort in that kind of project :) just to add more information ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The detailed answer is - it will be difficult - very difficult.
The **camera** from the stock samsung firmware **relies on the touchwiz framework** to work correctly. **Any AOSP based rom comes without the touchwiz framework** - and that's one of the best reasons to install an AOSP based rom. 
So what does this mean in the end?

You would need to modify the application - include the shared libraries and may have to port the framework - it won't be worth the effort. If you're not happy with the stock camera application, try one from the play store - they might even make better pictures.